# Understanding the meaning of set - - "$@" "-h"

Tags: bash, set, positional-parameter

I would like to understand what the following command does

```
set -- "$@" "-h"
```

The gnu manual says

```
--

  If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset.    
  Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the arguments, even if some
  of them begin with a ‘-’.
```

I cannot take much useful information from such description though.

As I understand it, the following appends `-h` to the function argument list.

```
set -- "$@" "-h"
```

But, how is it that the following actually replaces `--help` with `-h`, etc.

```
 printf '%s\n' "$*"
 for arg in "$@"; do
   shift
   printf '%s\n' "--> arg: $arg"
   case "$arg" in
     "--Version")   set -- "$@" "-V"   ;;
     "--usage")     set -- "$@" "-u"   ;;
     "--help")      set -- "$@" "-h"   ;;
     "--verbosity") set -- "$@" "-v"   ;;
     *)             set -- "$@" "$arg" ;;
   esac
 done
```

Comment: take a look at here https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-set-command#:~:text=Linux%20set%20command%20is%20used,tasks%20without%20facing%20any%20issue.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it adds `-h` to the end of the current argument list (aka the positional parameters).

Long answer: `"$@"` expands to the current argument list (i.e. the list of arguments passed to the current script, function, or whatever the relevant context is). `set -- whatever` *replaces* the current argument list with whatever's after the `--`. Thus, it replaces the current argument list with... the current argument list followed by `-h`.

For example, suppose we're in a script that was run with `./scriptname foo bar baz`. Then the argument list is `foo`, `bar`, `baz` (i.e. `$1` is "foo", `$2` is "bar", and `$3` is "baz"). In the script,

```
set -- "$@" "-h"
```

expands to the equivalent of:

```
set -- "foo" "bar" "baz" "-h"
```

...which sets the argument list to `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `-h`.